# Trouble compiling a simple C++0x program with lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, compiler-errors

I am trying to run a simple lambda example.

```
// lambda.cpp
#include <functional>
//#include <tr1/functional> 

int main()
{
   // Assign the same lambda expression to a function object.
   function<int (int, int)> f2 = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; };
   //function<int (int, int)> f2 = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; };
}
```

I'm compiling it like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -fpermissive lamdas.cpp
lambdas.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:    
lambdas.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
lambdas.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
lambdas.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
lambdas.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
lambdas.cpp:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
lambdas.cpp:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

How do I get it to compile with no errors?

Comment: What version of GNU c++ is this? I've never seen it spelling-correct source file names on the fly!

Comment: The lambda isn't the problem. You could replace it with something else, and you'd still get these errors.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think it's got style

Comment: @sehe: Hehe; they brought it in with C++0x support, guesstimating that the average human's ability to write basic words will completely vapourise after an hour with the new standard.

Comment: @sehe: I think, as _comments_ go, it definitely has style.

Comment: @Sachin: Why do you have the same line twice, once commented out?

Comment: @Sehe: Well spotted! I swear, "lambda" is the hardest word to spell right. It should be forbidden from any sort of example code, along with "initializer". So what's going on in that compiler call?

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprised the compiler did not substitute the equivalent ISO token `Λάμβδα` (or `λ`) in order to be totally standards conforming :)

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean `std::function`?

Standard library features live in the `std` namespace.

<sub>It's also interesting that your copy/paste is clearly fake; you wrote "lamdas.cpp" then compiled "lambdas.cpp"!</sub>

Comment: He also has `lambda.cpp` at the top of his source file!!

Comment: @Marlon: Certainly a sign of indecision!

Comment: Also known by some as the "stood" namespace :(

Comment: @sehe: I am using GNU 4.4 version of c++.

Comment: @Sachin: [Live example](http://www.ideone.com/CpG92) of the code working perfectly with `std::`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::function<int (int, int)> f2 = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; };
```

or, probably better

```
auto f2 = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; };
```

Comment: Dammit; it's past the 5 minute window in which I could have quietly stolen that good idea.

Comment: Worth remembering that the two alternatives are quite different.

Comment: Lambdas that don't capture anything are also implicitly convertible to function pointers.

Comment: @Tomalak: i tried using std::function but it doesn't seem to generate the same compile error.  Agree on the file name error and the copy paste mistake as well.

Comment: @Sachin: Of course it doesn't generate the same compile error. `std::` is the _solution_ for the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you forgot  -std=c++0x.